# When is glClear executed?

Tags: opengl, buffer

Consider these commands in OpenGL in given sequence:

```
glClearBufferuiv(GL_COLOR, 0, clearColor);
glClearBufferuiv(GL_DEPTH, 0, &depthValue);

..

glDraw(...)
```

Does the clearing of the default frame buffer happen immediately after clear command ? Or is it done during the draw call? (If its done during the draw call, then if I skip draw, will clearing of these buffers be skipped?)

Does the order of clearing color and depth buffer match the actual order specified? or the driver is free to implement it however it wants.

Comment: The driver is free to execute most commands whenever it feels like. You basically buffer up a command queue with most API calls and then it flushes the commands whenever necessary... but it will always do things that produce results consistent with the order you ask. Theoretically, this means that the color buffer and depth buffer could be cleared in a different order or in parallel if such a thing made sense, considering neither one explicitly affects the other. I'm not sure why any of this matters though - clearing buffers on modern GPUs is **extremely** fast since they use compression.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Why did you write this (perfectly good) answer as a comment?